# Print and Find The Position Of A Word And Words In A List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am set to make a program that ask the user for a sentence then the program should check if the sentence has punctuation such as `!"£$%^&*()[]#';,./<>?:@~}{_+-=`.

If it does not then it asks the user to type the word they want to find in the typed sentence. If the word is in the sentence then it should print the position of the word. If not then tell the user the word is not in the sentence.

Here is my go It's not pretty good:

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter sentence:')

if char is  sentence:
sentence = raw_input('Enter sentence:')

if char is not sentence:
word = raw_input('Enter word:')
while i is  sentence:
print i
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: you can use string.index() function for position

Comment: With all do respect...your code does not make any sense...where `char` is defined?...and how are you checking for punctuation?..and what happens if `sentence` has punctuation?...are you going to keep asking for a new `sentence`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
import string

sentence = 'Test this sentence'

if not any([symbol in sentence for symbol in string.punctuation]):
    # If no punctuations, continue ...

    # Ask word and get word ... , for example:
    word = 'this'

    position = sentence.find(word) # Returns -1 if word not in sentence.

    if position > -1:
        print position
```

Comment: while `set(string.punctuation)` ... `string.punctuation` is already a list of unique characters..

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me.